# Can I subscribe to window-docking events in windows 7 from C#

Tags: c#, windows-7

I am wondering if it is possible to create an application that could receive a notification when any other application/window is docked with the new windows 7 docking feature (f.ex. Winkey + left arrow)

The purpose of my application would be to set up custom rules for certain windows. So for example if I am using Chrome and I press the Win+LEFT keys, then my application would receive a notification, and would be able to say that the window should not resize to 50% of the screen, but should use 70%.

I am not very familiar with writing windows applications (mostly do web), so any pointers at how this might be achieved are very welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the Win+Left/Right combinations work with applications that pre-date Windows 7 I strongly suspect it is just a combination of [WM_SIZE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632646(VS.85).aspx) and [WM_MOVE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632631(VS.85).aspx) messages with coordinates worked out by the shell, and there is nothing to directly distinguish such a resize from any other within the application.

Use Spy++ from the SDK to prove this.

You could apply heuristics based on the screen size to detect these events.